# Loose binding of parameter names in WebApi routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Currently we use the below routing rules to cater for all our controllers; the advantage being that we don't have to define a route for each action in each controller:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("3", "{controller}/{action}/{arg1}/{arg2}/{arg3}");
routes.MapHttpRoute("2", "{controller}/{action}/{arg1}/{arg2}");
routes.MapHttpRoute("1", "{controller}/{action}/{arg1}");
routes.MapHttpRoute("0", "{controller}/{action}");
```

However due to this the parameter names in the methods must match; like so:

```
// Example method signature
public ResponseDto GetResponse(int arg1, int arg2)
```

If the parameter names are changed to something more friendly (eg: a name that would show the intention of each parameter instead of an ambiguous "arg1" name) like so:

```
// Better example method signature
public ResponseDto GetResponse(int userId, int itemId)
```

The binding would break unless:

- The routes and parameter names are explicitly defined
- The arguments are passed in using a query string

Is there are way to set up WebApi routing so it will automatically use the correct action based on the number of parameters; rather than the parameter names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you're trying to do something similar to what is described in [this good blog post on custom parameter binding](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-api-catch-all-route-parameter-binding). As you've found out, there is nothing out-of-the-box to support what you're trying to do.

At a conceptual level, HTTP is built around the concept of *resources*. A URI should identify a specific resource. Using generic positional "parameters" seems to blur the specificity of a resource. It seems that your use case might be better served by using the query string of the URI. That way, your HTTP API expresses a clear intent of what parameters are expected for a given resource.